# Azure Machine Learning - authorization error despite having maximum permissions

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to build a machine learning model on Azure for my company. The IT team at the company I work at has given me maximum permissions for our Azure Machine Learning account since I am doing all the setup part (we started using it only last month). However, I checked the portal and realized that I am not authorized to access any of the modules within Azure ML, namely Experiment, Models, Endpoints, Datasets, etc. Is there something I am missing that is giving me this error? The error message has this [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2161335) but I am not sure it serves the purpose.

**Note:** I am new to Azure so please forgive me if this is a very basic doubt.

[image]

Comment: Is there any ip restriction to access the resource ?

Answer (score 2):

any chance you could ask your IT team, exactly what permissions you have? can you also confirm that you have permissions on the all the resources (not just the workspace)? There are three associated resources you need access to besides the ML workspace: the storage account, the key vault, and the container registry.

try going to portal.azure.com to see if you can find those resources

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that the Workspace UI "Public network access" was set to "disabled" instead of "All networks".

I solved my problem by going to the "Networking" tab in the workspace and setting it to "All networks".

Then I was able to access all the jobs,experiments and notifications associated to the workspace.

In addition to that, the user with whom I access the workspace has Owner and Contributor roles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. It seems that the default configuration of azure ml network changes from terraform provider v2.99.0 to v3.81.0 and I was not understanding why I was getting a 403 error code.

Comment: That was my issue too, the default settings in the TerraForm provider were the issue. Great you brought it up, it was the same initial issue in my case.